# Converting Asp.net Membership to identity.How to verify Encrypted type format password into mvc identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cryptography, asp.net-identity

As per my understanding there are 3 password formats in mvc identity.

1. Clear- 0
2. Hashed - 1
3. Encrypted - 2

I am using .net mvc Identity 2 in my web application, and passwords are stored in encrypted (i.e 2) format in database

**EDIT :**

[image]

I wants to convert **Encrypted type format password into Hashed type format** in **C# code**

Please let me know if any further information require

Thank you.

Comment: What is the name of the column that store password format - 0, 1, 2? Could you show the screen shot?

Comment: @Win post updated..please check

Comment: What table is this? ASP.NET Identity doesn't have PasswordFormat column. Is this ASP.NET Membership?

Comment: @win your are absolutely right...yes its asp.net membership...i am converting membership to Identity .but the problem is password are stored in encrypted password..i am referring this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity..      and this blog is well explained for hashed password...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution of my own question, got a plain text by passing encrypted password. **my question was how to convert encrypted type password to hashed type**,but i got this solution (**converted encrypted password to plain text**) and my main aim was how to validate user with his password and its worked.

```
public class SqlMembershipProviderHelper : SqlMembershipProvider
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Used for decrypt password into plain text from encrypted type password
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="encryptedPwd"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string GetClearTextPassword(string encryptedPwd)
        {
            byte[] encodedPassword = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedPwd);
            byte[] bytes = this.DecryptPassword(encodedPassword);
            if (bytes == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0x10, bytes.Length - 0x10);
        }
    }
```

**Gets plain text by passing encrypted password and checked whether its validate or not**

```
SqlMembershipProviderHelper sqlmembershipproviderhelper = new SqlMembershipProviderHelper();
var existingPassword = sqlmembershipproviderhelper.GetClearTextPassword(password);
if (String.Equals(existingPassword , providedPasswordByUser, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
      return PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded;
}
else
{
      return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
}
```

**In webconfig added machine key**

```
<machineKey validationKey="1F82037DAE0E261ADEB1197B05F509D7043980F8060B712D255C98E3D606BB45183D3FF28839E90FD39618906469079DC6F3661704CC4E4D138179887B93D68E" decryptionKey="AFCF1E96D1734FADD42F1CECBFD7950B702F683A798905A5D1B281FACF258885" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you will need to decrypt those passwords created by ASP.NET Membership.

ASP.NET Membership uses ***Machine Key*** to encrypt the password. If the machine key was not explicitly set inside web.config, it was using the computer's MachineKey.

Easiest way is to use the exciting project, decryt those passwords, and create username and plain password pair in a temporary database table. Then you use those credentials to migrate users to ASP.NET Identity's ***AspNetUsers*** table.

As soon as migration complete, make sure to delete the temporary table.